# How to obtain subset of combinations only - combinations with restrictions

Tags: r, combinations

I will explain my problem in two different ways, please pick the one you understand better. If something's unclear please, tell me in the comments.

**Version 1**

For the sake of trying to make it clearer I will explain the same problem frm another point of view:

I have a binary matrix with 5 columns and 3 rows:

```
        [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
  [1,]    1    1    1    0    0
  [2,]    0    0    1    1    0
  [3,]    0    0    0    1    1
```

I am interested in (almost) all the versions of this matrix by permuting only the rows. There is one constraint: I only want the permutations where each column has at least one 1. As said above, I already calculated that there are 370 possibilities of permuting the rows maintaing at leat one 1 in each column. My question here is, is there a possibility obtaining these matrices without having to run through all the 1000 possible permutations?

**Version 2**

I would like to calculate some probabilities, for wich I have 3 tables of elements which  with each 10 columns which need to be combined.

```
Table 1: combn(5,3) -> 10 combinations
 > combn(5,3)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
    [1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    2    2    2     3
    [2,]    2    2    2    3    3    4    3    3    4     4
    [3,]    3    4    5    4    5    5    4    5    5     5

Table 2 & 3: combn(5,2) -> 10 combinations
 > combn(5,2)
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
  [1,]    1    1    1    1    2    2    2    3    3     4
  [2,]    2    3    4    5    3    4    5    4    5     5
```

Now I need to have all the combinations of the created groups, but only those who contain all possible elements at least once (1,2,3,4,5). There are 1000 possible combinations of which I am only interested in 370.

The only solution I can think about is to run through all the possible combinations (using `expand.grid()`  and check if all elements are present. I would hope there is an easier solution to this. Meanwhile this example is doesnt pose to much trouble to calculate, as soon as the number grow I could save lots of computation time if I could obtain directly only the combinations I am intersted in.

Comment: The fact that this has 28 views and not a single remark suggests that I'm not the only one that's having trouble understanding you. Could you go into a little more detail? Perhaps show what your result would look like? When you say, 'all the combinations of the created groups,' are you referring to the columns in the `combn` outputs?

Comment: Yes, you understand it correctly,I will try to make it clearer now, Thanks